# Consulta con ranking MYSQL

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, sql

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT nombreUsuario, sorteosGanados, @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rankGanadores

FROM Ganadores g, Usuarios u, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r 

WHERE g.idUsuario =  u.idUsuario
```

Que me muestra lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que yo necesito es que los dos valores de "nachomaldo1997" se transformen en 1 y los sorteos ganados se acumulen.

En que le estoy errando? Cuando hago un count(sorteosGanados) me acumula todos los sorteos ganados y me muestra solo 1 nombreUsuario (nachomaldo1997 - 3)

Muchisimas gracias de antemano

Comment: Me parece que tendrías que utilizar un `GROUP BY` por `nombreUsuario` para unir esos registros, y en el caso para acumular los sorteor ganados tendrias que utilizar `SUM(sorteosGanados)`

Comment: Además de un `sum(sorteosGanados)`, no? Creo que el group by no los suma, simplemente los "desaparece" si están repetidos...

Comment: Exacto XD, justamente estaba corrigiendo eso XD.

Comment: @Israel-ICM
Efectivamente gente! Muchisimas gracias.
Tanto el sum como el group by son correctos.
Mil gracias de nuevo.

Comment: @AntonioVenerosoContreras
Muchas gracias a vos tambien, Antonio. Podia etiquetar 1 solo por comentario